# What entitlements must I specify to use defaults write com.apple.screencapture in NSTask()

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, appstore-sandbox

I got the app working fine then went to submit to the app store and discovered this thing called the sandbox :-p

I have been reading the documentation and developer forums, but I cant figure out specifically what entitlement I need to add to get this working:

```
let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
    task.arguments = ["-c",
        "defaults write com.apple.screencapture type gif;killall SystemUIServer"]
    task.launch()
```

I've thought perhaps `com.apple.screencapture` and `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.shared-preference.read-write` as BOOLEAN YES might do the trick, but unfortunately not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it without NSTask and without the shell:

For defaults write use `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.shared-preference.read-write` and add the domain you'd like to modify (eg. com.apple.screencapture) and then use `CFPreferencesSetValue()`

For `killall` use `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events` and run an Applescript / send AppleEvents to terminate specific processes.

As you see, both entitlements are temporary and you need good reasons to get them pass the review. Goal of sandbox is that apps don't interfere with other apps. Especially terminating SystemUIServer can be very intrusive.

Comment: Could you post the example of CFPreferencesSetValue() implementation in swift?

Comment: @Jonathanff something along NSUserDefaults or just UserDefaults. Sorry I'm not fully fluent in swift. Maybe post a new question?